# How to build .Net Core 2.0 and .Net 4.6 projects in a single solution in VSTS Online

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-4.6, azure-devops

We are automating builds and releases on VSTS online. One solution contains .Net Core 2.0 projects as well as .net 4.6 project.

We have different build tasks on VSTS online for different projects. The builds are successful (includes NuGet restore). However, the DLL from the .NET 4.6 project is not working.

If we build the project on Visual Studio, and deploy it to Azure, it works fine. We observed that the binaries in both the cases differ.

Can someone help?

Comment: `The DLL [...] is not working`. Could you explain what seems to be the issue? What are the differences between the local and VSTS version of the assembly? Are you building for the right processor architecture (x86, x64, any)?
In short: give us some more info so we'll be able to help.

Comment: The DLL is actually wrapped as a service. The service does not respond. I am yet to be able to get more system level issues. However, if I replace the same with the version that I build on VS2017, it works fine. I see no difference between the settings of the two builds. However, it seems there might be differences in the dependencies when I do a NuGet restore.